# Compiling muPDF lib in Eclipse "cannot unlink `NUL': Invalid argument Android NDK" Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, mupdf

I'm trying to compile the muPDF lib in Eclipse on Windows 7. I'm following [these steps](http://www.mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android).

On this step

```
Build the native code libraries:
~/src/mupdf/platform/android $ ndk-build
```

I'm getting this error.

```
Qadir Hussain@GENETECH042 ~/mupdf/platform/android (master)
$ ndk-build
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/rm.exe": cannot unlink `NUL': Invalid argument
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored fo
r static libraries
      0 [main] rm 4244 stdio_init: couldn't make stderr distinct from stdout
      0 [main] rm 2876 stdio_init: couldn't make stderr distinct from stdout
      0 [main] rm 4832 stdio_init: couldn't make stderr distinct from stdout
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : mupdf <= mupdf.c
./obj/convert-dependencies.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
e:/android-ndk/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-binary.mk:391: recipe for target
 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 2
make: *** Deleting file 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o'
```

Also when I launch this command it creates a file NUL in my ..platform/android directory, the file has no extension and couldn't be deleted or renamed.

Comment: I think the problem is in `./obj/convert-dependencies.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. The failure with NUL is probably ignored.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 how to resolve this. I can show the mupdf.c file

Comment: @QadirHussain, There may be read/write permission issue on the downloaded a file as well check the library path in the .mk file.

Comment: Why don't you just import it as a project and run?